# Crash at PHPhotoLibrary presentLimitedLibraryPickerFromViewController line unrecognised selector send to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to present the Limited image picker but i get

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PHPhotoLibrary presentLimitedLibraryPickerFromViewController:]
```

I am using

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>
#import <PhotosUI/PhotosUI.h>
```

This line crashes although self is a viewcontroller

```
   [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] presentLimitedLibraryPickerFromViewController:self];
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick searching finds:

Possibly a "bug" ... possibly faulty documentation...

Add `PhotosUI.framework` to your target:

[image]

Comment: You were right! After so many hours, i even saw the videos of apple for this one. They didn't even mention that this framework should be added plus xcode does not even show any errors! Thank you!

Comment: @stefanosn - search is your friend. By the way, did this answer straighten out your scrollview delegate issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70992800/6257435

Comment: Fascinating. Usually, if you have the build setting “Link Frameworks Automatically” set (and “Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)”, too), when you `@import XXX;`, that framework is linked automatically, too. This is the first that I've stumbled across where that auto linkage isn't working.

Comment: @Donmag Havent found the time to check the code please give me some time to put it in my project to check is working. Thank you again for your help. I appreciate it!

Comment: @Rob It was so strange Mr Rob! But i still do not understand why xcode didn't give any errors when i import the photosUI header file!

Comment: @Rob - yeah, odd one... this post I found   https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658458 (Apple dev forums doesn't show date? but says "1 year ago"), states it's only a problem with Obj-C ... but is not observed with Swift. Another work-around is to add `-framework PhotosUI` to `Other Linker Flags`

Comment: It worked , well done.